# How can I represent the entity types depicted in an ERD as relations with attribute names?

Tags: database-design, schema, relational-theory, erd, database-diagrams

I have created the [entity-relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahoEy.png) (ERD) shown below (for brevity, each individual *bubble-shaped* box portrays multiple attributes):

[image: ERD]

Considering such an ERD, I have to *convert* each *entity type* or *associative entity type* depicted there as a *relation* with its corresponding *attribute names*, but I run into some problems.

I usually represent a relation as follows:

- `X = (a, b, c)`<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* Where `X` is the *name* of the *relation* and `a`, `b` and `c` are the *names* of its *attributes*.</sub>

Then, in the business domain that I am working on, a `Course` depends on zero-to-many (0:M) other `Courses` (as portrayed in the ERD). This means that a `Course` should be connected somehow to the `Courses` it is dependent on.

**So, how can I represent this situation as a (mathematical) *relation*?**

**Option 1**

I have tried the following:

- `Course = (course_number, course_name, course_dependencies?)`

**Option 2**

I think it is possible to depict the desired aspect in another way, e.g.:

- `Depends = (course_name)`

and then

- `Course = (course_number, course_name, depends)`

**Option 3**

But I thought about, maybe, arranging the elements as follows:

- `Course = (course_number, course_name)`
- `Depends = (course_name_depender, course_name_dependee)`

In this way, each pair of attribute names in the relation called `Depends` represents the association (or relationship) between two occurrences of the relation entitled `Course`.

**Questions**

Which of these options is the right way to do it? Perhaps there is a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the *Course* entity type that you describe, I have made the following assumptions:

- A *Course* is primarily identified by its *CourseNumber*
- A *Course* is alternately identified by its *Name*
- A *Course* is registered at a *CreatedDateTime*

So I reformulated the situation as follows:

- A *Course* is the dependent in zero-one-or-many *CourseDependences*
- A *Course* is the determinant in zero-one-or-many *CourseDependences*

Then, I supposed that:

- A *CourseDependence* is primarily identified by its *DependentCourseNumber* and *DeterminantCourseNumber*
- A *CourseDependence* is registered at a *CreatedDateTime*

This means, yes, that there is a conceptual-level many-to-many (M:N) association (or relationship) that may involve distinct instances of the entity type called *Course*. Such an association implies the existence of an *associative* entity type that, as noted, I denominated *CourseDependence*.

Consequently, from the set of formulations described above, I have derived the IDEF1X<sup>**1**</sup> diagram shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgQ3.png):

[image: Figure 1 - Courses Association IDEF1X Diagram]

In this way, employing the notation that you use to express relations along with their corresponding attribute names, I would represent (a) the *Course* entity type and (b) the *CourseDependence* associative entity type as two distinct relations in the following way:

- `Course = (CourseNumber, Name, CreatedDateTime)`
- `CourseDependence = (DependentCourseNumber, DeterminantCourseNumber, CreatedDateTime)`

Therefore, the *Option 3* exposed in your question would be very close to an accurate possibility to express the relevant aspects.

---

**Endnote**

<sub>**1.** *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the *United States National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) the early theoretical work authored by the *sole originator* of the [Relational Model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In general, you need **predicates** (relations) and **constraints**.

Start with a *predicate*, ..

**P1** Course named (C_NAME), assigned a course number (C_NUM), exists.

.. and *constraints*

**c1.1** *For each course name, exactly one course has that name.*

**c1.2** *For each course number, exactly one course is assigned that number.*

The predicate leads to relation; the constraints to -- well, constraints like: PK, AK, FK, CHECK etc.

```
Course {C_NUM,C_NAME} -- P1

   KEY {C_NUM}        -- c1.1
   KEY {C_NAME}       -- c1.2
```

**P2** Course number (PRE_NUM) is prerequisite for course (C_NUM).

**c2.1** *For each prerequisite course that course may be prerequisite for more than one course.*

**c2.2** *For each course, that course may have more than one prerequisite course.*

**c2.3** *A course can not be prerequisite to itself.*

**c2.4** *If a course has a prerequisite then that course must exist.*

**c2.5** *If a course is a prerequisite then that course must exist.*

```
Prerequisite {C_NUM, PRE_NUM}   -- P2

         KEY {C_NUM, PRE_NUM}   -- c2.1 & c2.2

       CHECK (C_NUM != PRE_NUM) -- c2.3

FOREIGN KEY (C_NUM)   REFERENCES Course (C_NUM)  -- c2.4
FOREIGN KEY (PRE_NUM) REFERENCES Course (C_NUM)  -- c2.5
```

And so on.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

---

Note:
I am using RDBMS wording for constraints, in general `KEY (PK, AK)` is an internal uniqueness constraint, foreign key is a subset constraint (inclusion), and `CHECK` is an internal value-comparison constraint.

---

And here is how it looks in an ERD; note that comments (grey) are not necessary, used only to illustrate the method. You may also note that it is not easy to express all the constraints here -- if comments are removed the [c2.3] will not be obvious.

[image: course_prerequisite]